# Using IF-ELSE inside a for loop of regex

Tags: regex, string, bash, for-loop

Sorry if the question is stupid :)

I need a script to search a series of strings in a file using a for loop, and output 'yes' if found and 'no' if not found

I have a text file 'reg.txt' . contents are below

```
sam=23 
jack=27 
jim=35 
dave=30
```

Script used. Contents r below

```
#!bin/bash
declare file="/oracle/TR4/test/reg.txt"
declare regex=( jack jim sal don )
declare file_content=$( cat "${file}" )
for i in "${regex[@]}"
do
if [[ " $file_content " =~ $regex ]]
then
echo " the name $i is found"
else
echo " the name $i is not found"
fi
done
exit
```

But while running script, it seems the condition is not searched properly. The output of ( $bash regcheck.sh )shown below

```
the name jack is found
the name jim is found
the name sal is found
the name don is found
```

It shows the name sal and don is found ! that's wrong.
Is there any special consideration while using 'regex', 'for loop' and 'if' together?
Please help

Comment: You want to match against `$i`, not `$regex` (which is equivalent to `${regex[0]}` and always expands to `jack`).

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning project, or beucase you really need this functionality. There are unix tools that already support what I think you're trying to do, without writing so much code. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, well this script is for learning or a demo I should say, but finally i want to do a similar task on production where I would want to search database parameter files to know if certain parameters are set (and if so display that line) or not. And then use that script to check on all the database in our env.  Could you name a few good Unix tools that could get my code shorter.  Thank you

Comment: @Salih : Given production env need, I would just go `grep -E 'sam=23|jack=27|jim=35|dave=30' file`. There is a whole family of `grep` options and versions, (zgrep, egrep, fgrep, ..) that are well worth the time invested learning about the various options/features available. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match against `$i` and not against `$regex`. Change your code to

```
if [[ " $file_content " =~ "$i" ]]
```

Entire code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare file="/oracle/TR4/test/reg.txt"
declare regex=( jack jim sal don )
declare file_content=$( cat "${file}" )
for i in "${regex[@]}"
do
        if [[ " $file_content " =~ $i ]]
        then
                echo " the name $i is found"
        else
                echo " the name $i is not found"
        fi
done
exit
```